# Why does casting this View as a Button stops my loop?

Tags: android, for-loop, android-view, android-button

I am trying to programmatically create buttons and add it to a linear layout. I am retrieving trivia questions from an API, which have a dynamic amount of possible answers.

I pass the list of answers to a function, then try to create a button for each answer:

```
   for (answer in answers) {
        // runs okay if you do not cast as button
        val answerButton = View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.answer_button, binding.answersLinearLayout) as Button

        answerButton.text = answer // but need to cast as button to set text
    }
```

This uses a layout which just contains my button in XML. Then I want to inflate this for as many answers I have to create a button for.

However, what is strange is when I DO NOT cast this inflated view as a Button, it will run properly and loop for how many answers I have. But when I DO CAST it to a Button, the button is inflated only once and does not run anymore (used breakpoints to confirm).

I need to cast this properly as a Button instead of a generic View because I need to set the text on the button.

Why does casting this as a Button suddenly breaks my loop? Is it exiting/breaking/returning the loop?

EDIT: This is my layout for R.layout.answer_button

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: show your layout `R.layout.answer_button`, a stack trace might also help assuming the cast is leading to an exception

Comment: any error or exceptions?

Comment: So I've just added the XML for my `R.layout.answer_button`. There are no errors/exceptions/crashes. It just makes one button in the loop, then stops (even when I can see List<String> size being 4).

Comment: Where is this code? Is it invoked on the main UI thread or a worker thread?

Comment: It should be on the UI thread. My fragment observes `answers` which is live data in my view model. Then it runs this code to receive the list of answers and makes a button for each one.

Comment: Okay, try to inflate the view simply and use the addView method to add it to the container in loop.

Comment: I'm suspecting it's the `setText` call that is not there in the working version and it's throwing an exception that gets swallowed somewhere without crashing the app. You can add try-catch with logging around the code to see if that is the case.

Comment: I wrapped it in a try catch and breakpoints tell me there's an exception being thrown. It's saying can't cast `Button` as a `LinearLayout`. So it looks like when I try to pass in the root linear layout for the buttons to attach to, the variable is seen to be the root linear view, not the button. So I just did `val answerButton = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.answer_button, null) as Button` instead and adding the view manually. It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your cast is being unsuccessful which is leading to the error.
You can however do the whole process programmatically like this.

```
 for (answer in answers) {
 LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
 Button button = new Button(this);
 button.setText(answer);
 button.setTextSize(20);
 button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 
 linearLayout.addView(button);
 
 this.setContentView(linearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
 }
```